# Enabling USB Access via Regedit

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have modified the **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/services/USBSTOR/Start** to **0x00000003**

But I still get a restriction message.
Flashdrive is accessible via opening via Portable Device, however permissions is only ReadOnly.

Comment: I very much doubt enterprise policies are applied by disabling the USB mass storage driver. Also, don’t try to circumvent enterprise policies.

Comment: Is there any way to bypass this?

Comment: If you *must* use USB devices for business purposes, you *will* get access – by talking to your boss, who will then notify the IT dept.

Comment: Lol. No. This is my personal computer.

Comment: whether your computer use for personal use. Any Enterprise antivirus do u use?